# Populating a column in Excel 2013 with VBA based on a multiple variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have three columns. Column A shows every date from 1/1/2016 to the end of the year. Column B is currently Empty. Column C shows a manually entered date (which can and does change(manually) often.

I want to have a Sub(through a button) that when pressed will populate column B with a "Yes" or "No" value depending on whether the value in the same row of Column A is greater than the value shown in Column C.

For example, as A1 (1/1/2016) is less than C1 (1/4/2016), B1 should show a "No". Whereas A5 (1/5/2016) is greater than C1 and should show a "Yes".

> ```
>     A            B            C
> 1/1/2016                  1/4/2016  
> 1/2/2016
> 1/3/2016
> 1/4/2016
> 1/5/2016
> 1/6/2016
> ```
>
> Should Become
>
> ```
>     A            B            C
> 1/1/2016        No        1/4/2016  
> 1/2/2016        No 
> 1/3/2016        No 
> 1/4/2016        No 
> 1/5/2016        Yes
> 1/6/2016        Yes
> ```

I am newer to VBA and haven't seen any questions directly related to this, so any simple VBA suggestions would be great to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally questions with no attempt to code an answer wouldn't be appropriate, but this should be an easy one and hopefully will give you enough so you can get started on these sorts of problems in the future. Try adding

```
'Col A = Col 1, Col B = Col 2, etc.
'Cells(row num, col num)
finalRow = Cells(1000000,1).end(xlup).row
for i = 1 to finalRow
    if cells(i,1) < cells(i,3) then
        cells(i,2) = "No"
    else
        cells(i,2) = "Yes"
    end if
next i
```

to your VBA editor.

Comment: This is perfect! I've incorporated it into my script and it's enabling me to get the results I want. I apologize as I'm new here so I'm still learning all the posting rules!

Comment: Best answer for actually doing it in VBA. The only thing I would change is Cells(1000000,1) to Cells(Rows.Count, 1)

Comment: Great. This reminds me a little of my first vba project. All the best in your future coding.

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to create a normal cell function. Type into B1

```
=IF(A1>C1,"Yes","No")
```

Copy that function to all the cells in column B and you have a result

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in B2,

```
=CHOOSE((A2>INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C$1:C2 )))+1, "No", "Yes")
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image]